# How fetech data one to many relationship in mysql and php

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table customer and second table orders. I have fetch the from customer but its fetch duplicate records.

```
select customers.name, customers.mobile, orders.Product
from customers,
     orders
where customers.id = orders.customer_id
```

Result :

[image]

Target :

[image]

Comment: save user information in one table, name, mobile number and use that user_id in order table as reference, for each table repeat user id

Comment: according to the images the query is not really returning duplicate records - there are pieces of information that are repeated but that is the nature of the query. To omit repeated pieces of information from display you need to keep track of the data in PHP. Also - I'm not sure you can be using both Laravel and codeigniter so why these tags?

Comment: I think you need `group_concat`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images (or links to images.) Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and _easier to convert to outer join_ if needed.

Comment: I would suggest looking at setting up a `hasMany` relationship between `Customer` and `Order`: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships. If you don't have those models set up then have a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` your `Customers` on `Order` column

```
select c.name,
       c.mobile,
       group_concat(o.Product) #products name separated by a comma
from customers c
left join orders o on
  c.id = o.customer_id
group by c.id
```

I'm not familiar with your structure but I guess that's the gist of what you're trying to get at